# Theme doesn't show up on tweak tool

Tags: 16.04, themes

I'm trying to change the theme on Ubuntu 16.04 . I downloaded it, extracted it in the /usr/share/themes folder and downloaded the Unity Tweak Tool to use the new theme. I launched Unity Tweak Tool but it wouldn't show up. I've also tried using the Gnome Tweak Tool with the same result. I'm trying to install a Windows 10 theme. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm guessing the theme is not a GTK+ 3 theme suitable for Unity or Gnome. If it's intended for windows 10 I'm not surprised.  If however its just made to look like windoze 10, you should tell us what DEsktop it's intended for (eg. lxde, lxqt, kde4, kde5, xfce...) and we may be able to provide more, or better check where you grabbed it from.

Comment: I got it from https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013482/ . It's intended for linux, it just changes the UI. @guiverc

Comment: thanks for link.  it states GTK 3.16 or higher is needed (16.04 GNOME uses 3.18) & works in Unity 7.x so it should work in yours. It could be you need to logout & log back in (so Unity 7 or GNOME resets itself & reloads the list of themes).

Comment: Thank you for your help @guiverc ! I'll try it and I'll be back with the result

Comment: I restarted my PC but it didn't fix the issue.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: I downloaded the .zip file & `scp` (copied) it to my x201 laptop (it runs 16.04). extracted it to a directory; then `sudo cp -prv ~/Win* /usr/share/themes/` (copied to system-wide themes folder), then loaded `unity-tweak-tool`. I could then select it & it changed my theme (*it didn't stay there long at all; i returned to my old theme...*)  I can only suggest trying again.  *I used the Unity 7 or default Ubuntu 16.04 DEsktop*

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to help. I'll do it from the start following your instructions.